# Why does sg-links force me to choose the Android app twice?

Tags: support, android-app

In recent months, tapping on a link in a Stack Exchange email to get to a question has started going through a third-party service, "sg-links". On Android (Android 4.4, KitKat) this pops up the app chooser as expected, but it is not for connecting to SE. It is for connecting to sg-links. Choosing, say Chrome, then briefly flashes the Chrome browser with an sg-links address and then pops up the app chooser again. This time, it will include the SE Android app. Tapping that finally gets me to the question.

What's going on here and is there a way to avoid the intermediate launching of the browser?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a third party service, it's owned and developed by Stack Overflow itself.

The full domain of the emails links is: `sg-links.stackoverflow.email`, the sg-links is just a sub domain without any real meaning. They can  choose anything, the only thing that really matters is the actual domain which is stackoverflow.email and that's what the browser is looking into.

The code running there is then redirecting to the actual page, leading to the second app choosing.